# Configuring Nginx and Gunicorn for DRF, Django and React Frontend

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I have an application whose frontend is in React and the back-end is in Django with API's developed using DRF for the front-end. Now I am using Nginx as the web server along with Gunicorn. The following is my Nginx conf file in sites-available:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;


 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 location /static/ {
    root /home/nokia-ui/build/;
}

location /nokia-sdn/api/v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/nokia-sdn/api/v1/;

}

location / {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/nokia-sdn/nokia.sock;
}
```

}

Now the when I access http://localhost:8000/ I get the login page, but I am not able to make any api requests to the back-end.Do we need to define the path of the API in nginx file, if so what is the format?

Comment: What happens with the API requests? What does the browser's network tab show in developer tools for these requests?

Comment: it show method not allowed error

Comment: Do your API requests use the path `/nokia-sdn/api/v1/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that Django is rejecting the API requests with a 400 response because of a mis-matching `Host` header. Those ajax requests are probably using `127.0.0.1` for their `Host` header, whereas you're initiating the main page using `localhost`.

You should tell Nginx to set the header in the location configuration for `/nokia-sdn/api/v1/` - for example:

```
location /nokia-sdn/api/v1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/nokia-sdn/api/v1/;
}
```